# How to Install GIPAW on Ubuntu with QE installation from Ubuntu Repositories

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso

I've just installed Quantum Espresso on Ubuntu using the command:

```
sudo apt install quantum-espresso
```

everything went well and I can run calculations on QE normally. But I want to install GIPAW, the commando to run gipaw.x is not found and I dont know where is the directory of installation to compile gipaw with the command:

```
make gipaw
```

Could someone help me?

Thanks
Levy

Comment: I do not know how you can do it if QE is installed from the apt repository like you did but if you compile QE from the source, compiling `gipaw` should be straightforward. You can check the [stand-alone gipaw installation instruction](https://github.com/dceresoli/qe-gipaw#stand-alone).